# How to map over dataframe, is it a tidyeval error?

Tags: r, dictionary, purrr, tidyeval, rstatix

Want to map over columns in a dataframe & perform t-tests with each column against a fixed column. Desired output would be a dataframe with each row(s) being t-test results - can use `map_dfr` once mapping process ok

Dug into tidy eval, not sure if it's a tidy eval error - any help much appreciated!

(`mtcars` as toy dataset)

```
library(rstatix)

# Test single cases - good
compare_means(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
compare_means(disp ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
compare_means(hp ~ cyl, data = mtcars)

# Trial map - fail

mtcars %>%
  map(~compare_means(.x ~ cyl, data = mtcars))

Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `.x` doesn't exist.
```

Following tidyeval guidance: https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/dplyr.html
Tried to see if quoting / unquoting was the issue, but no dice

```
# Abstract variables

test_data <- function(group_var) {
  quote_var <- enquo(group_var)
  data %>% compare_means(quote_var ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it may just be about *formula evaluation* specifially:

```
library(ggpubr)
library(tidyverse)

# Test data with 2 Species only
iris.subset <- iris %>% 
  filter(Species != 'virginica')
```

```
# Test single case
iris.subset %>% 
  compare_means(Sepal.Width ~ Species, data = .)

# Test direct map - doesn't work
iris.subset[1:4] %>% 
  map(~compare_means(. ~ Species, data = iris.subset))
```

Is it about formula evaluation? Test `as.formula()`

```
as.formula(paste0(names(iris.subset[1]), " ~ Species"))

# Pipe into test
names(iris.subset[1:4]) %>% 
  map_df(~compare_means(formula = as.formula(paste0(., " ~ Species")), data = iris.subset))
```

Success!!

Couldn't get an example to work with `mtcars` but will re-post if I do

Answer (score 1):

That's an NSE error, but not tidyeval. You're mapping over the vectors inside `mtcars`. You're not mapping over the column names of `mtcars`.

With `inject()` from the last rlang version you can do some NSE programming with non-tidyeval functions:

```r
names(mtcars) %>% map(~ rlang::inject(compare_means(!!sym(.x) ~ cyl, data = mtcars))
```

Three things are going on:

- We map over the *names* of the data frame.
- We transform the name to a *symbol*, i.e. an R variable.
- We inject that symbol into the formula using `inject()` and `!!`.

I have not tested the code.

Comment: Sounds convincing, but I can't test code either:

`names(mtcars) %>% map(~ rlang::inject(compare_means(!!sym(.x) ~ cyl, data = mtcars))) > Error: 'inject' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rlang'
`

I have `rlang 0.4.9` in `R 3.6.1`

Comment: I see it exported: https://github.com/cran/rlang/blob/master/NAMESPACE#L262. Have you restarted R after updating? If yes, try reinstalling after closing all your R and RStudio sessions (if you're on Windows it's easy to get installation issues).